# How to detect when user use program > file?

Tags: c, linux

I need to print text "Please, write something" if user run programm like "./programm". and don't print text in file if user use "./programm > file.txt". How can i detect, that user use redirect to file?
My code on C:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() {
    char buffer[100] = "It was readed...";
    int cb;
    write(1,"Vvedite\n", 8); // записываем в 1 текст Vvedite кол-во байтов 8
    cb = read(0, buffer+18, 80);
    cb+=18;
    write(1, buffer, cb);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Most existing tools I know which have that need, do use a commandline switch like `-i` "interactive" for that. Please explain why that (trusting in user to decide instead of guessing) is not an option.

Comment: Please do not change the behavior of your program based on the output file. `ls` does that and it is confusing and unnecessary. Use a command line switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`isatty()` call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to find out whether the standard output (`1`) is attached to a TTY (console).

Comment: Although `STDOUT_FILENO` is slightly nicer than the literal `1`.